# Where is the ruby on rails file cache stored on a mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

We're storing facets in the cache - basically calculating which search results will have results.  Arrays of ids are stored based on a cache key.

```
Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key) { calculate_facets(search_params) }
```

I want to inspect the file cache and see how large it is after testing and benchmarking.

And, would the total file size be similar (or related at all) to the amount of memory used if we switched to Memcache?

Comment: Rails file-based cache is in `<app dir>/tmp/cache` unless symlinked. Is this what are you looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks.